# Short declaration in Go

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and I don't understand how the code is allowing me to redeclare the same variable "**phones**". I thought you can only short-declare a variable once inside a function scope and then you can redeclare that variable only when you are declaring a new variable with it. But with the code below, I'm able to short-declare "**phones**" twice without declaring a new variable in the second short-declare statement.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    phones := map[string]string{
        "bowen": "202-555-0179",
        "dulin": "03.37.77.63.06",
        "greco": "03489940240",
    }

    multiPhones := map[string][]string{
        "bowen": {"202-555-0179"},
        "dulin": {"03.37.77.63.06", "03.37.70.50.05", "02.20.40.10.04"},
        "greco": {"03489940240", "03489900120"},
    }

  fmt.Println(phones)

  who, phone := "greco", "N/A"
  if phones := multiPhones[who]; len(phones) >= 2 {
    fmt.Println(phones)
    phone = phones[1]
  }

  fmt.Printf("%s's 2nd phone number: %s\n", who, phone)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go does not allow redefined variables in the same scope.
The code you have contains variables in two different scopes.
This is allowed in Go. It is not a problem.
Your code is similar to:

```golang
func main() { 
    name := "adam"
    if name := true; name != false {   // the var name here is in if scope.
 
        fmt.Println("name in if scope is :", name)
    }

    fmt.Println("name out if scope is : ", name)
    
    // name := "jawad" this is error. redifined in same scope not allowed.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> I thought you can only short-declare a variable once inside a function scope

No, this is wrong. Go  is block scoped, not function scoped.
Each variable can be declared once *per* *block* and `if` starts a new block.

(Note that this holds for any type of declaration, be it short or long.)